# Trac 1.4.2 - 403 forbidden error over customized logo

Tags: trac

After migrating from Trac 1.1.11 to 1.4.2, my customized company logo has been expelled:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) logo-foo.jpg:1

NB: that particular file is located in [my-path]/trac-foo/main/htdocs/logo-foo.jpg

Here is the conf/trac.ici setting for the customization:

```
[header_logo]
src = http://trac.foo.fr/logo-foo.jpg
alt = FOO
height = -1
width = -1
link =
```

The Trac workspace is served via Apache httpd as a web proxy.
So I added a section to /etc/httpd/conf.d/trac-foo.conf

```
<Directory [my-path]/trac-foo/main/htdocs>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

But that didn't fix the issue.
Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: NB: I tried to use local paths instead of URLs, but failed to match system directories with web mapping (/common) even with HTTPD aliases; I rather got 404 errors...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache 2.4? If so, you need to change your authorization directives. See [2.4 upgrade documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time).

```
-    Order allow,deny
-    Allow from all
+    Require all granted
```

Comment: Apache 3.0.5 it is, indeed. Will try. Thx